# Move list inside list to the end if both item identical

Tags: python, list

I have the following list of paired values :

```
a = [['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C'], ['D', 'D'], ['C', 'D']]
```

This list can contain one or more remarkable pairs that are made of the same item:

`['D', 'D']`

I'd like to move those pairs to the end of the list to obtain :

```
a = [['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C'], ['C', 'D'], ['D', 'D']]
```

I can't figure it out, but I believe I'm not too far:

```
a.append(a.pop(x) for x in range(len(a)) if a[x][0] == a[x][1])
```

Comment: `a = [pair for pair in a if pair[0] != pair[1]] + [pair for pair in a if pair[0] == pair[1]]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Straight-forward [sorting](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sorting-basics):

```
a = [['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C'], ['D', 'D'], ['C', 'D']]
a = sorted(a, key=lambda x: x[0] == x[1])
# [['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C'], ['C', 'D'], ['D', 'D']]
```

This simple [key function](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) works because `False` is sorted before `True` while mapping all pairs to only two keys maintains [stability](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sort-stability-and-complex-sorts). The downside to this approach is that sorting is `O(N_logN)`. For a linear solution without unecessary list concatenations, you could use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) with appropriate generators:

```
from itertools import chain
a = list(chain((p for p in a if p[0] != p[1]), (p for p in a if p[0] == p[1])))
```

Comment: Note that sorting takes `O(nlogn)` while my solution below takes `O(n)`. A very creative solution though

Comment: @SomethingSomething True.

Comment: @SomethingSomething Can you please demonstrate that it's only O(nlogn)? I'm trying to but so far failed. When I sort random floats I do observe O(nlogn) behavior but when I sort random bools I observe O(n) behavior.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I don't know what sorting algorithms are used there. In the general case, when there is no restriction on the type and the range of the input, a sorting cannot take less than `O(nlogn)` time complexity. That is what I meant. Maybe Python checks the type of the input and uses `O(n)` algorithms that can run under certain conditions.

Comment: @SomethingSomething It doesn't appear to be about the type. When I use `lambda _: random.choice((0.1, 0.2))` as the key, I observe O(n) behavior as well.

Comment: @StefanPochmann It should be about having only two distinct values in the list. Idk much about timsort, but any quicksort derivate would have the list sorted after the first pivot which would be `O(N)`.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Good point with quicksort. But Timsort as far as I know is pretty much *mergesort* (optimized by detecting already sorted runs, which shouldn't help with random choices from two values). I'm pretty puzzled right now.

Comment: Sorting according to length of sets could also work : `sorted(a, key = lambda x: -len(set(x)))`

Comment: Ok I think I now know why. Maybe I'll write a question+answer about it, but I'd first need to fully read what Timsort does in order to be sure...

Answer (score 6):

Use list comprehensions:

```
a = [pair for pair in a if pair[0] != pair[1]] + [pair for pair in a if pair[0] == pair[1]]
```

Note that a more efficient solution would be

```
identical = []
not_identical = []
for pair in a:
    if pair[0] == pair[1]:
        identical.append(pair)
    else:
        not_identical.append(pair)
a = not_identical + identical
```

It is more efficient, as here you iterate `a` only once, whereas in the list comprehensions solution, you iterate `a` twice. Still, both solutions take `O(n)` time complexity and `O(n)` space complexity, which are better (and more natural for this problem), than a sorting solution.

Comment: I doubt that the second will be more efficient. While it is true that you are only iterating the list once instead of twice, but the highly optimized comprehension should make more than up for that.

Comment: @schwobaseggl agreed. I wonder why this answer does not get upvotes. Maybe people who ask such a basic question feel bad when they see Python's list comprehensions (else they would probably not ask the question)

Comment: Despite its higher time complexity, I guess mine is simpler and more concise and performance won't be an issue even for very long lists (as log(n) doesn't grow that fast). Add to that that list concatenation is `O(M+N)` which is unnecessary and that users tend to trust rep without proper checking ;)

Comment: I generally agree with you. `O(N+M)` is `O(n)` here, since if the first list is `O(n)` then `M+N = n`. Anyway, as you say, whereas `n` is sane, a sorting is totally fine. Liked your answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want your original solution to work, you can do something simple like this instead:

```
a = [['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C'], ['D', 'D'], ['C', 'D']]

for i, pair in enumerate(a):
    if pair[0] == pair[1]:
        a.append(a.pop(i))

print(a)
# [['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C'], ['C', 'D'], ['D', 'D']]
```

This however is `O(N^2)`, because of `pop(i)` in the for loop, which is `O(N)` itself. `pop()` is only `O(1)` if you pop from the end of a list.

You could also group using a dictionary by the length of lists sets, which is `O(N)` if you avoid sorting at the end and just use `min()` and `max()`, both of which are `O(N)` operations.

Here is an example:

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = [['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C'], ['D', 'D'], ['C', 'D']]

d = defaultdict(list)
for sublst in a:
    key = len(set(sublst))
    d[key].append(sublst)

result = result = d[max(d)] + d[min(d)]

print(result)
# [['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C'], ['C', 'D'], ['D', 'D']]
```

Of course, as shown by @schwobaseggl, you can also accept the `O(NlogN)` approach of sorting:

```
sorted(a, key = lambda x: -len(set(x)))
```

Answer (score -1):

Just collect all the duplicates in a list and at last extend the list :

```
a = [['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C'], ['D', 'D'], ['C', 'D']]

no_dub=[]
dub=[]
for i in a:
    if i[0]==i[1]:
        dub.append(i)
    else:
        no_dub.append(i)

no_dub.extend(dub)
print(no_dub)
```

output:

```
[['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C'], ['C', 'D'], ['D', 'D']]
```